# Orderby using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I want to convert the following SQL query in LINQ

```
Select * from EmpCode order by Left(EmpCode,4) Right(EmpCode4)
```

Is it possible to make a LINQ query like this?

Comment: I'm sure you can, anymore questions? Also it would be awesome if your made sure you syntax is correct before posting

Comment: i'm not sure what that order by Left(...)Right(...) does in Sql. But in linq you have orderBy(x => x.Date) or orderByDescending(x => x.Date)

Comment: This is no valid SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can read your typos correctly

```
var result = listOfEmpCode.Orderby(x => x.SubString(4))
                          .ThenBy(x => x.SubString(x.Length-4))
                          .ToList();
```

Note : this doesn't check for valid string length.. add pepper and salt to taste

---

[Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey> Method (IEnumerable, Func<TSource, TKey>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a
> key.

[Enumerable.ThenBy<TSource, TKey> Method (IOrderedEnumerable, Func<TSource, TKey>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in
> ascending order according to a key.

[String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
> specified character position and has a specified length.

[Getting Started with LINQ in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq)